# RTL orienting TOC and typesetting Estern Arabic Numberals in Arabxetex

Tags: table-of-contents, arabic

I am using arabxetex package and need my TOC oriented from right-to-left as well as to have page numbers be in Eastern Arabic Numberals i.e (٠‎ ١‎ ٢‎ ٣‎ ٤‎ ٥‎ ٦‎ ٧‎ ٨‎ ٩‎)?

Table of Contents should look like this:   (صصض....... ٣)
Here is a minimal example:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage[margin=0.08in, paperwidth=3.56in, paperheight=5.95in]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{AAA} % Instead of AAA, I need Arabic text ننن
\begin{arab}[utf]
نتنتنهه
\end{arab}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textarab[utf]{ يسيس}} % Instead of BBB, I need Arabic text ههه
\begin{arab}[utf]
منسة
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type Arabic natively, then use xelatex and `polyglossia`, not `arabxetex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{انا عجم لا عرب}
الخلیج الفارسیه

\end{document}
```